# Proving the contracted Bianchi identity?

Tags: differential-geometry

From Lee's book, the differential Bianchi identity states that for the Riemann curvature tensor,
$$R_{ijkl;m} + R_{ijlm;k} + R_{ijmk;l}=0$$
The the proof is, contract on $i, l$, and then on $j, k$ after raising an index on each pair.
Then we obtain the "contracted Bianchi identity"
$$2R_{ij;}^j = S_{;i}$$
where $R_{ij}$ is the Ricci tensor, $S$ is scalar curvature, and the indices after semicolon denoting the component of the covariant derivative with respect to that index.

First, how do we contract on $i, l$? Isn't it only correct to contract on the placement of the index (e.g. the first and the last index)?

I can use symmetry to make the second term $-R_{ijml;k}$, then contract on the first and fourth index. But then I don't know how to contract $i, l$ for the last term
$R_{ijmk;l}$ since then I can't use symmetry of the curvature tensor.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's the idea: define a covariant $5$-tensor $T$ by
$$T_{ijklm} = R_{ijkl;m} + R_{ijlm;k} + R_{ijmk;l}.$$
The differential Bianchi identity says that $T$
is the zero tensor. 
First contract $T$ on its first and fourth indices, yielding a $3$-tensor $U$ which
is also zero:
$$0 = U_{jkm}=  T_{ijk}{}^i{}_m = R_{jk;m} - R_{jm;k} + R_{ijmk;}{}^{i}.$$
Then contract $U$ on its first two indices:
$$0 = U_{j}{}^j{}_m = S_{;m} - R_{jm;}{}^{j} - R_{im;}{}^{i}.$$

Comment: Thanks. Your books are fantastic by the way, I very much enjoy reading them.